# Microsoft Graph: Get preview image

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom, microsoft-graph, requestexecutor

I created a SharePoint-Add-In (provider hosted) which serves as a proxy for retrieving information from `Microsoft Graph`.
From the client I issue AJAX requests to my MVC-based web service which in turn calls the endpoint of the `Graph API`.
Currently I attempt to get my "trending items" from

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/trending`

which works quite well.
The response contains JSON objects that have a property

`previewImageUrl`

The property, though, does not contain any URL with a picture but provides me wit an endpoint for an `octet-stream` - it looks like this:

`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/{gibberish}/items/{more gibberish}/thumbnails/0/small/thumbnailContent`

This means I need to go there, fetch those bytes and make an image from them. So far I tried opening a `ClientContext` and retrieve the credentials - yet there are none (`ClientContext.Credentials == null`) and issuing the call leads to `HTTP 401`. Calling the URI from the browser yields a `HTTP 403`.
My host web is

`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sub/site`

could it be that something is preventing a cross-domain call?

Calling SharePoint using the CSOM works fine though, I get the host web and the current user.

I use SharePoint Online (duh!) and have a provider hosted add-in on-prem.
What do I need to do to fetch the image data?
Thank you for your help.

**tl;dr**

Situation:

- provider hosted SharePoint-Add-In on SharePoint online tenant
- add-in serves as a proxy for client to call `Microsoft Graph` API (works fine)
- calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/trending` works fine, too
- JSON result contains a property `previewImageUrl` for each item
- `previewImageUrl` references a URI such as `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/{gibberish}/items/{more gibberish}/thumbnails/0/small/thumbnailContent`, type of such is `octet-stream`
- host web URL is of the pattern `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sub/site` whereas `previewImageUrl` refers to root site collection (see bullet above)
- no add-in web

Attempts (and fails):

- calling the URL from browser gives `HTTP 403`
- calling the URL from the .NET backend gives `HTTP 401`

  - `ClientContext.Credentials == null`
  - `ClientContext.Authentication == Anonymous`
  - using WebRequestExecutor does not help (passing credentials from ClientContext)
  - using any other means of `HttpWebRequest`-like classes fails
- granting `tenant read` permissions to the add-in does not help either
- finding proper documentation on [MSDN](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/insights_resourcevisualization)

Working:

- authenticating against `Microsoft Graph` using Azure AD
- calling endpoints from `Microsoft Graph` API
- using CSOM to get current web (host web) and current user by creating user client context

What do I need to do to get those bytes?
Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find the answer for this? I'm in a similar situation, where I'm using the MS Graph API to get trending items for the user, and that works fine, but when I try to get the data from previewImageUrl, I get authorization errors, and I can't figure out how or where to get the right token for that URL.